# Comparing sums of elements within an array to determine which is the highest

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, compare, element

I am trying to create a single function in Javascript that will take each element of an array of numbers (specifically phone numbers in this case) and determine which element has the highest sum. I have reached a point where I am feeling pretty defeated, yet I think I am very close. Can anyone give some guidance? This is what I have so far:

```
function highest(inputArray) {
  var sum = 0;
  var currentHighest = 0;
  var largest = 0;
```

I set the variables I am going to use, then created a for loop to iterate over each element in the array.

```
  for (a = 0; a < inputArray.length; a++)
    var tempArray = inputArray[a].replace(/\D/g,'');
```

I create a place holder string to remove any non integers in the element, then create a function that will sum all the digits of the element.

```
    function sumDigits(str) {   
        for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                sum += parseInt(str.charAt(i));
        return sum;
        }
    }
```

Then create an if statement that tests if the sum of the current element is higher or equal to the highest sum element.

```
    if (sumDigits(tempArray) >= currentHighest) {
          currentHighest = sum;
          largest = inputArray[a];
          return largest;
        }
        else {
            return largest;
        }
    }

var newArray = ['123-456-7777', '963-481-7945', '111-222-3333'];
console.log(highest(newArray));
```

Here is the entire code block as a whole:

```
function highest(inputArray) {
  var sum = 0;
  var currentHighest = 0;
  var largest = 0;
  for (a = 0; a < inputArray.length; a++)
    var tempArray = inputArray[a].replace(/\D/g,'');
    function sumDigits(str) {   
        for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                sum += parseInt(str.charAt(i));
        return sum;
        }
    }
    if (sumDigits(tempArray) >= currentHighest) {
          currentHighest = sum;
          largest = inputArray[a];
          return largest;
        }
        else {
            return largest;
        }
    }
}
var newArray = ['123-456-7777', '963-481-7945', '111-222-3333'];
console.log(highest(newArray));
```

I get "undefined" as the result when I run the code if that helps. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: It looks like you're not reseting the value of `sum` between calls to `sumDigits()` but you should be. Am I looking at it right? Very hard to look at the code this way in separate blocks. Can you edit to put it all together the way it really is?

Comment: Thank you all for the quick respsonses. Jonathan you were quite right, the issue was sum was not being reset between calls. Turned out to be a quick fix

Comment: Are you missing an open curly brace after the `for` loop?  If you don't supply one, for loops will just execute the first statement after it, which I'm thinking isn't the expected behavior (indentation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting this question correctly (add each number of a phone number, then print the largest result), you can accomplish it like this:

```js
//Define an array of phone numbers
var numbers = ['123-456-7777', '111-222-3333', '963-481-7945'];

//Map takes an array, does something with each element, then returns that result
var sums = numbers.map(function (m) {
    //In this case, we return an object containing the original number, and a score
    return {
        number: m,
        //The score is calculated by adding up each number.  The match expression creates an array of all terms (g modifier) matching the expression.  \d matches a single digit, so we end up with an array of each digit in the number.
        //Reduce applies a function to each item in an array, and adds them up
        score: m.match(/\d/g).reduce(function (p, c) {
            //This looks like magic, but the + before p and c coerces them to numbers (they're strings right now, since match returns an array of strings)
            //Both numbers are then added
            return +p + +c;
        })
    }
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    //Now that we have the scores of all numbers, we can sort the array to find the highest score
    //To be honest, sort() is mostly trial and error for me to find which values to return 1 and -1 for
    if (a.score < b.score) return 1;
    if (a.score > b.score) return -1;
    return 0;
});

//All together, without comments:
sums = numbers.map(function (m) {
    return {
        number: m,
        score: m.match(/\d/g).reduce(function (p, c) {
            return +p + +c;
        })
    }
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.score < b.score) return 1;
    if (a.score > b.score) return -1;
    return 0;
});

console.log(sums);

document.write("Number with the highest score: " + sums[0].number);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("It's score is " + sums[0].score);
```

Which prints the number with the largest sum to the console.  The sum of the numbers is also available in the object that is returned in the `score` property.

Comment: Thank you Scott. That function does achieve what I was trying to accomplish. Unfortunately most of that surpasses my knowledge of Javascript. The above code was the best I could do with my limited experience.

Comment: @davidshibley No prob!  I've updated it to include some documentation, and also fixed a bug.  If you're using this code, make sure to add the `+` before `p` in the `reduce` call.

Comment: Is there a way of changing this code so that in the event of a tie ("965-481-5945" and "963-481-7945" for instance) that it would output the latter instead of the first?

Comment: @davidshibley Yep, you should be able to change the `return 0` line in the sort function to instead return `1`.

Comment: perfect! brilliant. Scott... I think I love you haha. Thank you again for the elaborate response. Very educational, I am glad I decided to ask this question here.

Comment: @davidshibley My pleasure, thank *you* for being willing to learn!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not initializing the `sum` variable here and you are prematurely returning the `sum` value in this function:

```
function sumDigits(str) {   
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(str.charAt(i));
        return sum;
    }
}
```

It should be this:

```
function sumDigits(str) {   
    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(str.charAt(i), 10);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

We can't really see what else is wrong without seeing all the code together in one block so we can see how different parts call each other and interact.

---

Here's a more compact solution (assuming you're trying to sum the digits in each phone number):

```js
var phoneNumbers = ["123-456-7890", "982-111-9999"];
var sums = phoneNumbers.map(function(p) {
    return p.match(/\d/g).reduce(function(sum, num) {
        return sum + parseInt(num, 10);
    }, 0);
});
var maxSum = Math.max.apply(Math, sums);

// output results in the snippet window                    
document.write("sums = " + JSON.stringify(sums) + "<br>");
document.write("maxSum = " + maxSum + "<br>");
```

Here's how it works:

1. Run `.map()` on the phone numbers array with the goal of returning an array of sums.
2. Within the `.map()` search for all digits, then run `.reduce()` on that resulting array to accumulate the sum.
3. Then, to get the max value in the `sums` array, use `Math.max()` which can accept the entire array and do the max work for you.

Comment: Added comments about two observations of things that are wrong in your `sumDigits()` function.

Comment: Fantastic response, thank you jfriend! Thank you for the explanation both of what went wrong with my code and the explanation of your revised version.

Comment: @davidshibley - since it looks like you're relatively new to StackOverflow, are you aware that if you get your question answered, you can select a "best answer" by clicking the green checkmark to the left of that answer.  This will earn both you and the person who provided the answer some reputation points which will eventually lead to earning more privileges on the site.  After you earn some more reputation points, you can also "upvote" any answer that helped you by clicking the up arrow by it.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you. Yes I am new to this site, signed up a few months ago but never used it. I am relatively new to programming in general. I do apologize though for not mentioning the fact that the answer needed to be in basic Javascript only. Unfortunately the code you provided (though informative and eloquent) won't run with what I am working with :-/

Comment: @davidshibley - what are you working with that needs "more basic" Javascript than this?  This is ES5 level Javascript which is widely supported in browsers.  In the future, please include ALL relevant requirements in your question.  Or is this homework and you want to stick to more basic structures that you've already learned?

Comment: My apologies. It does work perfectly fine. I guess I saw JSON (I know nothing of JSON) and got scared. I will be more cautious of how I respond in the future. It was not for homework, it was a programming challenge I came across that I could not solve. I am currently solely self-taught.

Comment: @davidshibley - the only reference to JSON is so that I can show the results in the StackOverflow snippet - you would presumably not be using that.  But even so, `JSON.stringify()` is also ES5 and widely supported back to IE8.  FYI, I'm self taught too.